# Limit IO speed on ZFS pool

Tags: usb, zfs

I want to limit the speed of a ZPOOL I have on a USB external device (facing overheating issues otherwise). I know I could just trash the device but trying to save the planet. It works fine at lower speeds but overheats when going max.

I set up a ZPOOL on the device because I saw in the Oracle ZFS documentation a guide how to set such limits: https://docs.oracle.com/en/operating-systems/solaris/oracle-solaris/11.4/manage-zfs/setting-i-o-bandwidth-limits.html

But trying in Ubuntu I get errors for any of those properties:

```
zfs get -r effectivewritelimit internal-usb
bad property list: invalid property 'effectivewritelimit'
```

I guess it is a different implementation (ZFS vs. OpenZFS) that doesn't have that feature? Is there any other way or is this drive doomed to the landfill?

Thanks!

Comment: The simplest way would be to limit the USB transfer speed, but it means taking a USB 3.x device and setting it to USB 2.0 (or from 2.0 to 1.1).